# I have two select list with knockout bindding,but when i change view model's value,the select don't update correctly

Tags: knockout.js

I have two select list . And I use ko.utils.arrayFilter method to change my select list.
Everything is good when i use it to do "Add Field" or "Remove Field".

But when i changed the viewmodel,then i click the "Add Field" or "Remove Field" the select list won't update correctly.

```
        self.test = function(){

            var idx =  self.rightSeleted();
            var selectedField = $.grep(self.availableFields(), function(n, i){
                return n.FieldNameId == idx;
            });
            debugger;
            var currentValue = selectedField[0].IsAsc();


        };
```

my sample code is in here http://jsfiddle.net/knupA/

Did i do something wrong when bindding select list ?!

Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knupA/1/), and it seems to work. I changed your method to select from the arrays to use the Knockout method, and I removed your test method, as that was being called when nothing in the right dropdown was selected, so was blowing up.

```
var selectedField = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.availableFields(), function(item){
                return item.FieldNameId == idx;
            });
```